# 144hz working... partially?

Tags: monitor

I will get straight to the point.

I've tried changing the monitor rate in Ubuntu display settings to 144hz

I've tried also changing the rate using `xrandr`

And 144hz works only partially. What do I mean? My mouse cursor is definitely refreshing at 144hz, but almost all Ubuntu UI is working at 60hz (it's just lagging for me). I didn't have that problem on Windows. Scrolling in Firefox is also choppy as on 60hz.

What could be the problem?
I don't think it's the hardware problem, as I had Windows and everything worked fine.

I have Ryzen 5 1600 @ 3.8GHz and GTX 970 GPU with 16 GB of RAM.

It could be marked as duplicate, but nothing helped me so far.

I would really appreciate any help, as I'm completely new with Linux and especially Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox still refuses to work with 144hz. [I found this website](https://testufo.com/) that lets you check what fps your monitor and most importantly browser is running in. You can see that firefox caps out at 60 fps. Chrome and other chromium based browsers apparently don't have this issue on my system, so best I can suggest is to switch to a chromium based broswer.

Comment: I'm currently using Firefox on Windows with 144hz and it works really well, I'd say even better than Chrome in my case. Maybe it's an issue with Linux version of Firefox?

Comment: Yes indeed. I've seen multiple complaints all from linux users of firefox. On windows, no hiccups.

Comment: That's pretty disappointing, it's been 3 years since I had that issue and it's still not resolved? woah.